# It says "TypeError: Oppnadjur() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" why?

Tags: python, typeerror

so this is my function, and it doesn't work.. why?

```
def Oppnadjur(djurfil):
    djurfil = open("djur.txt", "r")
    Djur = djurfil.readlines()   
    Djur.sort() 
    djurfil.close()

    Djurlista=[]
```

Comment: You need to post more code. Your example doesn't contain a call to `Oppnadjur` but the error in the question title suggests that there is a problem with a call to `Oppnadjur`...

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that your function should receive one parameter, `djurfil`. However, you clearly did not mean to do that, as you proceed to not use that parameter, overwriting it with a different value. See [the Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) about how to define functions.

The error message you see means that you had called your function as you had intended, with no parameters (`Opnnadjur()`), but that's not how you had defined it. So Python is looking for the parameter it thinks you should be passing in.

Answer (score 0):

The error would be in your calling code, not the def of the function. You need to call `Oppnadjur` with one parameter. The error message suggests that you are calling it with zero parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You define your function with one argument (`djurfil`), but the argument is unused in your function so you can get rid of it.

```
def Oppnadjur():
    djurfil = open("djur.txt", "r")
    Djur = djurfil.readlines()   
    Djur.sort() 
    djurfil.close()

    Djurlista=[]
```